# Using bash to generate random IPs Issue

Tags: bash, shell, ip-address

I have a list of URL and I'm trying construct a firewall log with that list.
Example:

```
$ cat urls.csv 

a.com
```

I know how to construct the log with IP directly mentioned as variable.

```
$ cat processor.sh 

#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
while read -r line
do
   URLS="$line"
   IP='10.109.1.1'
   today_date=`date +%d/%b/%Y`
   conact_1=" - - ["
   concat_2=":00:00:00 +0000] "
   date_concat=$conact_1$today_date$concat_2
   GET='"GET '
   protocol=' HTTP/1.1" 304 0 304 0 0 0 655 456 645 368 0'
   final_url=$IP$conact_1$today_date$concat_2$GET$URLS$protocol
   echo $final_url
done < "$filename"
```

Result:

```
$ bash processor.sh urls.csv

10.109.1.1 - - [22/Jul/2018:00:00:00 +0000] "GET a.com HTTP/1.1" 304 0 304 0 0 0 655 456 645 368 0
```

Now If i have a log line of `50 or 100` or even more , How can I generate random IP for the total number of URLs and generate a log line ?

```
$cat urls.csv

a.com
b.com
c.com
d.com
....
```

Any suggestions on how to generate random IPs in bash?

Expected Result:

```
$ bash processor.sh urls.csv

1.1.1.1 - - [22/Jul/2018:00:00:00 +0000] "GET a.com HTTP/1.1" 304 0 304 0 0 0 655 456 645 368 0
1.1.1.2 - - [22/Jul/2018:00:00:00 +0000] "GET b.com HTTP/1.1" 304 0 304 0 0 0 655 456 645 368 0
1.1.1.3 - - [22/Jul/2018:00:00:00 +0000] "GET c.com HTTP/1.1" 304 0 304 0 0 0 655 456 645 368 0
1.1.1.4 - - [22/Jul/2018:00:00:00 +0000] "GET d.com HTTP/1.1" 304 0 304 0 0 0 655 456 645 368 0
............
```

Comment: `date_concat=$(date +" - - [%d/%b/%Y:00:00:00 +0000] ")`; the format string isn't restricted to the special escape characters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For IPv4, the basics would be:

```
printf "%d.%d.%d.%d\n" "$((RANDOM % 256))" "$((RANDOM % 256))" "$((RANDOM % 256))" "$((RANDOM % 256))"
```

You'll probably want to filter out `192.168.0.0/16` and `10.0.0.0/8` and a *lot* of other addresses.  For IPv6, you might try:

```
for ((i=0;i<8;i++)); do printf "%02x%02x:" $((RANDOM%256)) $((RANDOM%256)); done | sed 's/:$//'
```

(`$RANDOM` only generates values up to `2^15-1`, so `$((RANDOM%65536))` is pointless)

Comment: perhaps one need to do `printf "%d.%d.%d.%d\n" "$((RANDOM % 256 ))" "$((RANDOM % 256 ))" "$((RANDOM % 256 ))" "$((RANDOM % 256 ))" `

Answer (score 2):

Works as expected based on Inder's answer.

$cat processor.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
while read -r line
do
   URLS="$line"
   #IP=$(printf "%d.%d.%d.%d\n" "$((RANDOM % 256 ))")
   IP=$(printf "%d.%d.%d.%d\n" "$((RANDOM % 256 ))" "$((RANDOM % 256 ))" "$((RANDOM % 256 ))" "$((RANDOM % 256 ))")
   #IP='10.109.1.1'
   today_date=`date +%d/%b/%Y`
   conact_1=" - - ["
   concat_2=":00:00:00 +0000] "
   date_concat=$conact_1$today_date$concat_2
   GET='"GET '
   protocol=' HTTP/1.1" 304 0 304 0 0 0 655 456 645 368 0'
   final_url=$IP$conact_1$today_date$concat_2$GET$URLS$protocol
   echo $final_url
done < "$filename"

$ bash processor.sh input.csv
103.137.94.111 - - [22/Jul/2018:00:00:00 +0000] "GET a.com HTTP/1.1" 304 0 304 0 0 0 655 456 645 368 0
74.123.232.234 - - [22/Jul/2018:00:00:00 +0000] "GET b.com HTTP/1.1" 304 0 304 0 0 0 655 456 645 368 0
102.13.8.154 - - [22/Jul/2018:00:00:00 +0000] "GET c.com HTTP/1.1" 304 0 304 0 0 0 655 456 645 368 0
210.106.160.230 - - [22/Jul/2018:00:00:00 +0000] "GET d.com HTTP/1.1" 304 0 304 0 0 0 655 456 645 368 0
```

Comment: I just did a minor correction its still williams answer and credits :)